# HQL - List in where clause which can be null, using H2 and MySQL

Tags: spring, hql, h2

I have the following code in Hibernate Query Language:

```
     @Query("SELECT a FROM Table a " +
            "WHERE (COALESCE(:param, null) IS NULL OR a.value in :param) "
    )
    List<InspectionInstruction> findAllInIds(@Param("param") List<Long> ids);
```

The call is either with a List of Ids, or just with null. So I want to use the where clause if the list is not empty, if it is empty,  I want to omit the where clause. The actual query is much bigger and has multiple clauses, so splitting them up is not a viable option.
It works great with MySQL (Version 8), however using it with H2, I get the following error:

```
WARN [http-nio-auto-1-exec-4] --- o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 50004, SQLState: HY004
ERROR [http-nio-auto-1-exec-4] --- o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: Unknown data type: "NULL, ?"; SQL statement:
select a0_.id as col_0_0_ from table a0_ where coalesce(?, null) is null or a0_.id in (?) [50004-214]
```

My H2 connection string:

```
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL 
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

Is there a way of handling possible null values as param in H2? I could also pass an empty list instead of null, if that has any advantage.

Comment: Why you use `coalesce(?)` instead of `?`? In SQL, `COALESCE` should always have at least two arguments.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I was trying so much today already, just edited it back to how I used to do it. But didn't make a difference.

Comment: H2, unlike many others, compiles prepared statement immediately (for better performance), but due to this feature H2 needs to know data types of parameters when they are used inside some expressions, so an explicit cast (`CAST(? AS BIGINT ARRAY)` etc.) can be needed in some cases.

Comment: That's nice to know, thank you. But I believe I just fixed it. I used `coalesce` because I was used to it. But when I remove the `coalesce` alltogether, it works in both mysql and h2. I don't even need the `MODE=MYSQL` in the h2 connectionstring. I actually can't explain why I used coalesce. Because if the list is null, it literally reads `WHERE null is null` so that should work anyway.

Comment: Ok now i get `unexpected AST node: {vector}` wher the null check is, because it translates to "WHERE elemenet_0, element_1 is null which is bad syntax.

Comment: And I also remember why I used `COALESCE`, because if the List has more than one element, I need it for the null check, otherwise I either get the mentioned error, or Operand should contain 1 column(s) if I put :param in brackets.

Comment: `CAST(? AS java.util.UUID)` works great for 0 ore 1 values, but it doesn't for more than 1 unfortunately. `AS BIGINT ARRAY` just throws an error, I think it only needs one word after AS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer I was looking for, but one that works:
I played around with some `CriteriaBuilder` implementation but as HQL is used throughout the entire project and I also like to write HQL statements because they are close to SQL, I ended up doing it like this:

```
     @Query("SELECT a FROM Table a " +
            "WHERE (:paramEmpty IS TRUE OR a.value in :param) "
    )
    List<InspectionInstruction> findAllInIds(@Param("param") List<Long> ids, @Param("paramEmpty") boolean idsEmpty);
```

Which is a bit of an ugly method in my opinion, but it does the job.

I also found the size() function, got excited, but it doesn't support parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade H2 to the version `1.4.200`

My colleague suggest that we can change this condition from:

`AND (COALESCE(:accountNames) IS NULL OR account.accountName IN :accountNames)`

to:

`AND (:#{null eq #accountNames} is true or account.accountName in :accountNames)`

I've tested with Oracle and H2 (Mode Oracle) with Spring Boot 2.7